# Latin words over this door?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, motto, inscription

We took our son to college and this was written over one of the doors on campus.  I cannot figure out what it means!  Can anyone here help?  I assume it is Latin, but...

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Literally, "force wins". (Force/violence/strength/power, overcomes/overpowers/overtakes.)

Comment: I guess I now need to know how it is pronounced.  Can you send me a phonetic spelling or something?

Comment: An astonishing thing to write on the portal of a seat of learning.

Comment: @tony. No, it cannot mean that.

Comment: @fdb: it's superAT, not superARE; yes, of course it is, silly me! Perhaps this building was once a training school for a right-wing police force?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's something along the lines of "Strength Overcomes", or "Strength Conquers".

Comment: Vis means “force” in the singular and “strength” in the plural, so it should be “force overcomes” or “force conquers.”

Comment: Thank you also, this site is awesome.  I've been using those web translator apps for months to no avail, and companies that specialize in translation wanted over a hundred dollars...